# Import variables into main file and have them available in other file that are imported into main

Tags: sass

Say I have an `index` scss file in which all my other smaller scss partials are imported into:

```
@import "color-vars";
@import "scss_that_uses_the_color_vars";
```

`scss_that_uses_the_color_vars` looks as follows:

```
p {
   background-color: $mainColor;  // ERROR: undefined variable $mainColor
}
```

However, I did define `$mainColor` in `color-vars` which I imported *before* `scss_that_uses_the_color_vars` in the `index` file ... how can I make it work whilst preserving the modularity?

I say "whilst preserving modularity" because I don't want to simply insert `@import "color-vars";` in `scss_that_uses_the_color_vars`, since that would make it very hard to debug when all my smaller modules import each other. I.e. that would result in a total mess! Therefore, I would like to define the flow of imports in the `index` file, but this, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be possible?

Answer (score 0):

### For such purposes the [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) rule should be the optimal decision.

> Members (variables, functions, and mixins) loaded with @use are only visible in the stylesheet that loads them. Other stylesheets will need to write their own @use rules if they also want to access them. This helps make it easy to figure out exactly where each member is coming from.

```
// scss_that_uses_the_color_vars
@use 'color-vars';

p {
   background-color: $mainColor; 
}
```

```
// index
@forward 'scss_that_uses_the_color_vars'; // or `@import`, but read belows paragraph
```

On a side-note `@import` is deemed depricated, to ensure the functionality of your Sass code in the future, concidering to generally switch to [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) or [`@forward`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward) might be worth the thought.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen, you should concidere switching to Dart Sass alltogether. LibSass is [depricated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated). If you are using Node Sass the migration is "straightforward", you can find it [here](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated) under "How do I Migrate".

Comment: I am pretty sure I am not using Dart Sass, but `@use ... as ...` works.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen, well, then happy coding!